Accessing Indices Beyond Array Size in Decompiled UEFI BIOS Code
I am stuck analyzing an .efi file (extracted from a UEFI BIOS .exe package). I have commented and renamed most of the parts I am interested in, but I am having some troubles finding the last parameters I need.
The decompiled snippet code look like this:
  isModelWhenZero = isModel_X_or_Y(MODEL_SERVICE_TAG_4);
  if ((isModelWhenZero == 0xffff) ||
     (*(longlong *)(&ADDR_ENCODE_PARAMS_X + isModelWhenZero * 24) == 0)) {
    resultInfo = L'\x02';
  }
  else {
    initArrayMemoryZero((undefined8 *)INITIAL_DATA,16);
    initArrayMemoryZero(ENC_BLOCK_SERIAL_TAG,32);
    copyArrayContent(ENC_BLOCK_SERIAL_TAG,MODEL_SERIAL_7,size);
    charCodeAt(local_74,(ulonglong)MODEL_SERVICE_TAG_4,4);
    copyArrayContent((undefined8 *)((longlong)ENC_BLOCK_SERIAL_TAG + size),(undefined8 *)local_74 ,4)
    ;
    encoderModel_X(INITIAL_DATA,(longlong)ENC_BLOCK_SERIAL_TAG,rol,F2,F3,F4,F5,
                      *(uint **)(&ADDR_ENCODE_PARAMS_X + isModelWhenZero * 24));
    applySHA256ToCoded((byte *)INITIAL_DATA,16,(undefined8 *)FINAL_CODE_RESULT,local_78,(byte *)0 x0,
                       0);
    calculateSuffix_8FC8(SUFFIX_TYPE_CHAR,SUFFIX_SIZE_?,FINAL_CODE_RESULT,MODEL_SERVICE_TAG_4);
    resultInfo = 0;
  }

I am stuck in the ADDR_ENCODE_PARAMS_X  data. That address is passed to the encoderModel_X() as a parameter, and inside that function is accessed like this:
      A = A | *ADDR_ENCODE_PARAMS_X ;
      B = B ^ ADDR_ENCODE_PARAMS_X [1];
      C = C | ADDR_ENCODE_PARAMS_X [2] - p;
      D = D ^ ADDR_ENCODE_PARAMS_X [3] + p;

      A = A | ENCODE_PARAMS[4];
      B = B ^ ENCODE_PARAMS[5];
      C = C | ENCODE_PARAMS[6] - p;
      D = D ^ ENCODE_PARAMS[7] + p;

if (ADDR_ENCODE_PARAMS_X [10] != 0) {

j = ADDR_ENCODE_PARAMS_X [11];

So by the look of it, I would say it is an array and when I look in the memory map I see this on that address:
ADDR_ENCODE_PARAMS_X                         
        0000a9c8 00              ??         00h
        0000a9c9 00              ??         00h
        0000a9ca 00              ??         00h
        0000a9cb 00              ??         00h
        0000a9cc 00              ??         00h
        0000a9cd 00              ??         00h
        0000a9ce 00              ??         00h
        0000a9cf 00              ??         00h

PTR_TABLE_SUFFIX_X                      
        0000a9d0 80  a2  00      ds *       s_0Q2drGk99WLJ1...

So an array of size 8, but what I don't understand is the references to the index > 7. For example, ADDR_ENCODE_PARAMS_X [10]. What is this accessing? The next part PTR_TABLE_SUFFIX_X? Or I am missing something here?
Thank you in advance for any help!!

If you are statically analysing the file, Ghidra is not showing you the size of the arrays, that's lost during compilation. What you see is Ghidra naming that location due to a reference or a string. You can see that the params are indexed by multiplying by 24, so you can expect each entry to be 24B long. Which would match the index 11 if those accesses are WORDs. BTW, if you are trying to crack a firmware, often you don't need to fully RE the custom encoding/cipher, just copy it's binary code and use it with custom params (if this applies to your case).

@MargaretBloom do you know any resource/blog where I can check that way of cracking the firmware? The one I am trying to revert is very similar to other that is reverted, but I am uncapable of finding the initial params to pass to the function.
In theory they should be on the memory address that I pasted on the post. But there are only 0s on that position, so I don´t know what else to check or where to look on the .efi file (I am really noob on all this topic of reverse-engineering)
